I cant login with the default MongoDB credential I set during deployment
I am currently deploying MongoDB database on a Kubernetes cluster. I am currently using a Statefulset and the pods are running, but I cant login with the default credentials I set in the Statefulset manifest.
These are the manifests I am using at the moment.
Statefulset Manifest
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  namespace: mongo
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:latest
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: username
                  name: mongodb-config
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: password
                  name: mongodb-secret
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--bind_ip_all"
            - "--config=/etc/mongo/mongodb.conf"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-volume
              mountPath: /data/db
            - name: mongodb-config
              mountPath: /etc/mongo
      volumes:
        - name: mongodb-config
          configMap:
            name: mongodb-config
            items:
              - key: mongodb.conf
                path: mongodb.conf
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mongo-volume
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storageClassName: local-path
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi

Configmap
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: mongo
  name: mongodb-config
immutable: false  # Indicates that the ConfigMap can be modified
data:
  username: admin  # Sets the value of the "username" key to "admin1"
  mongodb.conf: |  # Defines the content of the MongoDB configuration file
    storage:
      dbPath: /data/db  # Sets the MongoDB data storage path
    replication:
      replSetName: "rs0"

Secret
apiVersion: v1
data:
  password: UGFzc3dvcmQK    #base64 value for Password@
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: mongodb-secret
  namespace: mongo

Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: mongo
  name: mongo  # Specifies the name of the Service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: mongo  # Specifies the name of the port
      port: 27017  # Specifies the port number
      targetPort: 27017  # Specifies the target port on the pods
  clusterIP: None  # Specifies that no cluster IP is assigned (Headless Service)
  selector:
    app: mongo

This is the outcome when I run this command
mongosh --host localhost --port 27017 -u admin -p Password@ --authenticationDatabase admin

Current Mongosh Log ID: 673dc9349d4791ba0dc1c18b
Connecting to:          mongodb://<credentials>@localhost:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&authSource=admin&appName=mongosh+2.3.3
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.

But when I run mongosh --host localhost --port 27017
I get this outcome
ubuntu@achebe-2:~$ mongosh --host localhost --port 27017 
Current Mongosh Log ID: 673dcc91af14392b9cc1c18b
Connecting to:          mongodb://localhost:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.3.3
Using MongoDB:          8.0.3
Using Mongosh:          2.3.3

For mongosh info see: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/

test> 

I have tried using a keyfile while also setting authorization: enabled in the security portion of the configmap.
Name:         mongodb-config
Namespace:    mongo
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
mongodb.conf:
----
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db  # Sets the MongoDB data storage path
replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"
security:
  keyFile: /etc/mongodb-keyfile/keyfile
  authorization: enabled

username:
----
admin

BinaryData
====

Events:  <none>

For the Keyfile I made modifications to the statefulset manifest
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
  namespace: mongo
spec:
  persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy:
    whenDeleted: Retain
    whenScaled: Retain
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  serviceName: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: fix-keyfile-permissions
          image: busybox:1.34
          command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - |
              cp /etc/mongodb-keyfile-secret ~/keyfile
              chmod 400 ~/keyfile
              chown 999:999 ~/keyfile
              cp ~/keyfile /etc/mongodb-keyfile/keyfile
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongodb-keyfile-secret
              mountPath: /etc/mongodb-keyfile-secret
              subPath: mongodb-keyfile
            - name: mongodb-keyfile
              mountPath: /etc/mongodb-keyfile
      containers:
      - command:
          - mongod
          - "--replSet"
          - "rs0"
          - "--auth"
          - --bind_ip_all
          - --config=/etc/mongo/mongodb.conf
          - --keyFile=/etc/mongodb-keyfile/keyfile
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          value: "admin"
          valueFrom:
             configMapKeyRef:
                key: username
                name: mongodb-config
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: password
              name: mongodb-secret
        image: mongo:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: mongo
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongodb-keyfile
          mountPath: /etc/mongodb-keyfile
        - mountPath: /etc/mongo
          name: mongodb-config
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: mongodb-keyfile-secret
        secret:
          secretName: mongodb-keyfile-secret
      - name: mongodb-keyfile
        emptyDir: {}
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          items:
          - key: mongodb.conf
            path: mongodb.conf
          name: mongodb-config
        name: mongodb-config
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: mongo-volume
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
      storageClassName: local-path
      volumeMode: Filesystem
    status:
      phase: Pending


And the above didn't work either.
Please what am I doing wrong. How do I prevent login without credentials.

Try starting mongod with authorization disabled and no keyfile.  That should permit you to connect and list users so you can see what was created.

You can connect to every MongoDB without credentials, i.e. when you run mongosh --host localhost --port 27017 then you are connected but not authenticated. Thus you cannot receive any authentication error. On the other hand, when you try to connect with username/password then authentication may fail. When you are connected without authentication then you are connected but you cannot run any command, apart from commands like db.listCommands() or db.help(), etc.

I have no clue about kubernetes, but it looks like to define parameters twice. Once in config-file and once as command line options. That's pointless (at least you set the same parameter values). Where is the replica set initiated? Where does it create the user? Did you have a look at mongod log-file?

Regarding your last question "How do I prevent login without credentials?" It's not that simple. You need to authenticate with x.509 certificates instead of username/password and set net.tls.mode: requireTLS and net.tls.allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: false

Your base64 encoded password does not look correct. UGFzc3dvcmQK decodes to Password not Password@. The correct encoding is UGFzc3dvcmRA.
One thing you can do is define your secret manifest using stringData field instead of data, to have the Kubernetes API perform the encoding for you:
apiVersion: v1
stringData:
  password: Password@ ### WILL BE BASE64 ENCODED WHEN APPLIED
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: mongodb-secret
  namespace: mongo

